# Git: Remove commit tree from history

Tags: git, branch, commit

I have done some rebases to fix my repo, but it didn't really help.

So my repo currently looks like this:

```
              C1 --- ... --- Z1  (no-branch)
             /
A --- B --- C --- ... --- Z       master
```

I'm kinda lost now.
I have all the commits I need on my master branch, so I just want to get rid of C1 to Z1. They are not in a branch, `git branch --contains C1` displays nothing, although tools like gitk and SourceTree say that theese commits exist.

How can I fix my repo?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure those commits aren't referenced anywhere? Try `git show-ref`

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Yes, I'm sure. [See this](http://s23.postimg.org/v957yr88b/no_ref.png)

Comment: `git show-ref`, no arguments? Also look at the contents of any files under `.git` with `HEAD` in the name.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Yes, you were right! **Thanks a lot**, I got it solved after spending the whole day searching the web for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I had some tags on the commits in the tree from C1 to Z1, so thy could not be removed by `git prune` for example. Looking at git `show-ref` I found the tags referencing SHAs that did no exist in my tree.